# NgModel in parent-component supposed to reflect state in child-component

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a library which contains a component that is a wrapper around a primeng-component. Everything is based on Angular 10.

The primeng-component has a `ngModel`. I want to set the `ngModel` in the parent-component which accesses the wrapper-component and I want the `ngModel` to be 'reflected' back to the parent-component when it's changed down in the primeng-component.

The parent includes the wrapper like this:

**parent.component.html**

```
    <div class="col">
      <wrapper-autocomplete
        [suggestions]="projects"
        ngDefaultControl
        [ngModel]="selectedProject"
        (ngModelChange)="changeSelectedProject($event)"
        [field]="'name'"
        (completeMethod)="getProjects($event)"
        [forceSelection]="true">
        
        ...

      </wrapper-autocomplete>
    </div>
```

In the parent I set `[ngModel]` to a variable with the name `selectedProject` which is part of the parent-component. The component reacts to changes by using the `ngModelChange` where I insert my own function:

**parent.component.ts**

```
 changeSelectedProject(event: any) {
   this.selectedProject = event;
 }
```

In the wrapper-component I include the primeng-component like this (abstracted, doesn't show all properties for readability):

**wrapper.component.html**

```
<p-autoComplete
  ...
  [ngModel]="ngModel"
  (ngModelChange)="ngModelChangeCallback($event)">

  ...

</p-autoComplete>
```

And the ts-part of the code looks like this (also cut down for readability):

**wrapper.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autocomplete-list.component.css']
})
export class AutocompleteListComponent {

  @Input() ngModel: any;
  @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  ngModelChangeCallback(event: any): void {
    this.ngModelChange.emit(event);
  }
}
```

So, this works and does reflect the changes back to the parent, but it is not really what I want to achieve. The component is supposed to be used by other people in the future and I want them to be able to bind the model with only using `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)=...`.

Do you have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? I found out about the [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) which seems to be what I need, but I was unable to properly implement it in my code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know you can implement custom ControlValueAccessor. so just let me just do it for you here

```
<p-autoComplete
  ...
  [ngModel]="value"
  (ngModelChange)="ngModelChangeCallback($event)">

  ...

</p-autoComplete>

@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autocomplete-list.component.css'],
  providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => AutocompleteListComponent ),
            multi: true,
        }
    ],
  })
export class AutocompleteListComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

    onValueChange: any; 
    value: any;

    writeValue(val: any): void {
        this.value = val;
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onValueChange = fn;
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {}
    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {}

    ngModelChangeCallback(event: any): void {
      this.onValueChange(event);
    }

}


// then in use it like this

  <wrapper-autocomplete
     [suggestions]="projects"
     ngDefaultControl
     [(ngModel)]="selectedProject"
     [field]="'name'"
     (completeMethod)="getProjects($event)"
     [forceSelection]="true">
       
     ...

  </wrapper-autocomplete>
```

What I did above is implements a custom Control Value Processor. It has 4 methods

1. **writeValue(val: any)** --> it will invoke when ever the parent mgModel change/update something
2. **registerOnChange(fn: any)** --> it will invoke at component initialization and you can store that function in some variable and then everytime you want to emit something to parent simply pass data to that function like above.
3. **registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {}** and **setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {}**
   You can ignore it for now as it might not be needed right now. but they are helpful when you want to register touch or disabled state.

***Another easy way is to use Banana in a box trick***

Just replace your input output to other name instead of ngModel

```
export class AutocompleteListComponent {

  @Input() input: any;
  @Output() inputChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  ngModelChangeCallback(event: any): void {
    this.inputChange.emit(event);
  }
}

 <wrapper-autocomplete
   [suggestions]="projects"
   [(input)]="selectedProject">  </wrapper-autocomplete>
```

Comment: I used your first approach and that is exactly, what I wanted. In fact, my first implementation was pretty close to that but it seems I used the provider wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ControlValueAccessor` is what you need, but there is another trick for this issues with less code.

Just rename the `ngModel` in your child component with `Smth` or anything you want and the output will be `SmthChange`. Then you can bind `[(Smth)]` magically.